# A bounded sequence that does not converge with $x_n \neq x_m$ for $n \neq m$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

I wanted to check that the sequence I have come up with correctly answers the following question:

> Give an example of a bounded sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ which is not convergent and is such that $x_n \neq x_m$ for $n \neq m$.

The sequence I have devised is $$x_n = \begin{cases} x_{n-1} + 0.1 + (0.1)^n & \text{for } x_{n-1} < 0.9 \\ x_{n-1} - 0.9 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
with $x_1 = 0$.

I believe that $x_n \in [0,1)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and meets the other two criteria. The idea behind the sequence is that it moves closer to 1 but then always drops back down to around 0, thus avoiding convergence and keeping the function bounded. We add a $(0.1)^n$ term to make sure no two values are the same, without really increasing the value of $x_n$ much over time.

I have generated the first 12 numbers in the sequence and everything seems to be fine, but I just wanted to check I haven't missed anything obvious. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not just $\frac 1 n$ for $n$ even and $1-\frac  1n$ for $n$ odd?

Comment: @geetha290krm That's much nicer. I figured there was a way simpler way to do this. Thanks.

Comment: While your function is more complicated, you are correct that it does have the required properties.